# If file with name in folder than create new file with new name - with shell script

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I want to run a shell script to gather Twitter data with [t](https://github.com/sferik/t).
I don't want to overwrite existing files so how can I define s.th. like

If there is a file called **twitter.csv** in the folder then create a new file called **twitter2.csv** ... or open **twitter.csv** and add new data

```
cd data

t timeline @twitter --csv --number 3000 > twitter.csv

cd ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file=twitter.csv
[[ -e $file ]] && file=twitter2.csv

t timeline @twitter --csv --number 3000 > "$file"
```

If you want to generalize this so it looks for the first unused `twitter<N>.csv`, you could do:

```
file=twitter.csv; i=1
while [[ -e $file ]]; do file=twitter$((++i)).csv; done

t timeline @twitter --csv --number 3000 > "$file"
```